# using fourier method to compute this integral

Tags: fourier-analysis

> Use the method of Fourier analysis to calculate the following
>   integral:
>
> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+4x^2} \operatorname{d} x .$$

Could someone help about this question? what skills should I use? Should I change the $\cos$ function to $\exp$?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043730/evaluate-integral-using-fourier-analysis).

Answer (score 2):

One can see $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+4x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+4x^2}dx$ as the Fourier trasform of $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2(1+4x^2)}$ valuated in 1, which gives $\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{e}}$.

Comment: Sorry,how can i get pi/2sqrt(e)??

Comment: I edited. The Fourier transform $\widehat{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{2(1+4x^2)}=\frac{1}{4}\pi e^{-\frac{|k|}{2}}$. This integral can be performed using the Residue Theorem.